# Error with "cake build:browser" and Uglify.js -- Cannot read property 'Array' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, uglifyjs

I just installed Uglify.js and tried to use it to rebuild CoffeeScript, but keep getting this error.  This happens when I type "cake build:browser" in the CoffeeScript directory.  (I want to try my hand at modifying the CoffeeScript language.)

My Uglify.js was cloned from GitHub and the symbolic link was created in .node_libraries. Uglify is installed correctly, confirmed since it runs properly in Node and through the command line.  So maybe this is a CoffeeScript problem.

Help?

```
/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:475
                        return options.defines[name];
                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Array' of undefined
    at get_define (/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:475:47)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:527:32)
    at walk (/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:215:47)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:164:59)
    at walk (/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:220:36)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:146:43)
    at walk (/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:220:36)
    at /Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:1643:37
    at Array._block (/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:81:34)
    at walk (/Users/myuser/projects/UglifyJS/lib/process.js:220:36)
```

Comment: I dunno, I'd say it's working fine.  That looks pretty ugly to me.

Comment: Hahaha, good point cwolves.  I'm going to clarify the question a little since UglifyJS is working, but it's not working properly with how I'm trying to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was able to replicate this. But why are you cloning the UglifyJS repo? If you just do `npm install uglify-js` to install to the local `node-modules` directory (with npm 1.x), everything runs fine.

Similar issue: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/issues/140

Comment: I figured cloning it and setting up symlinks would work just as well as using npm, but apparently not.  Yesterday, as a work around, I switched to the Google Closure Compiler, but today, from your hint, I just deleted what I had of uglify-js and reinstalled via npm, and it seems to work.  If anyone reads this in the future, just delete UglifyJS and reinstall via npm.